# How to write unit test for connection factory in Spring webFlux

Tags: mockito, database-connection, spring-webflux

```
@Component
public class DisplayOverrideRowMapper {
    public DisplayOverride mapRow(Row row, RowMetadata meta) {

        return new DisplayOverride(
                row.get("store_auth_override_id",Integer.class),
                row.get("item_no",String.class),
                row.get("item_dsc",String.class),
                toForceOnlineOffline(row.get("display_override_type",String.class)),
                row.get("billing_division_no",String.class),
                row.get("store_no",String.class),
                row.get("in_store_flg",Boolean.class),
                row.get("pickup_flg",Boolean.class),
                row.get("delivery_flg",Boolean.class),
                row.get("ship_flg",Boolean.class),
                row.get("reason_cd",Integer.class),
                row.get("effective_dt", LocalDate.class),
                row.get("expiration_dt",LocalDate.class),
                row.get("last_update_ts",LocalDate.class),
                row.get("last_update_user_id",String.class));
    }

    private DisplayOverrideType toForceOnlineOffline(String displayOverridetype) {
        switch (displayOverridetype) {
            case "offline":
                return DisplayOverrideType.FORCE_OFFLINE;
            case "online":
                return DisplayOverrideType.FORCE_ONLINE;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The below **func** method I want to write unit test for

```
    @Autowired
    public OverridesRepositoryHelperImpl(DisplayOverrideRowMapper displayOverrideRowMapper,
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.displayOverrideRowMapper = displayOverrideRowMapper;
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<DisplayOverride> func(DisplayOverrideRequest displayOverrideRequest) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(SELECT_GET_OVERRIDE);
        String results = buildWhereClauseForGet(displayOverrideRequest);
        sql.append(results);
        return Flux.from(connectionFactory.create())
                .flatMap(c ->
                        Flux.from(c.createStatement(sql.toString()).execute())
                                .map(result -> result.map((row,meta) -> displayOverrideRowMapper.mapRow(row,meta)))
                                .flatMap(p -> Flux.from(p))
                                .doFinally(st -> c.close())
                );
    }
```

Can any help me in writing the unit test for this **func** method. As i wrote this but it not covering the all the lines of **func** method as when I am stubbing the connection.create() method then the actual code does not shows any coverage

When I use the debugger it goes inside this line **connectionFactory.create()).thenReturn((Publisher) Flux.just(connection)** but it not going further inside

```
    @MockBean
    DisplayOverrideRowMapper displayOverrideRowMapper;

    @MockBean
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @MockBean
    Connection connection;

    @MockBean
    Result result;

     Flux<DisplayOverride> displayOverrideResponseFlux = Flux.just(displayOverrideResponse); // I already created this so you don’t need to worry about it

        Mockito.when(displayOverrideRowMapper.mapRow(any(), any())).thenCallRealMethod();

        Mockito.when(connectionFactory.create()).thenReturn((Publisher) Flux.just(connection).flatMap(
                c -> Flux.just(result)
                        .map(result -> result.map((row, meta) -> displayOverrideRowMapper.mapRow(row, meta)))
                        .flatMap(p -> Flux.from(p)).doFinally(signalType -> c.close())));
```

```
OverridesRepositoryHelperImpl overridesRepositoryHelper = new OverridesRepositoryHelperImpl(displayOverrideRowMapper,connectionFactory);
Flux<DisplayOverride> Result = overridesRepositoryHelper.func(displayOverrideRequest)
```